# Given 5 colors to choose from, how many ways can we color the four unit squares of a $2\times 2$ board

Tags: probability

Given 5 colors to choose from, how many ways can we color the four unit squares of a $2\times 2$ board, given that two colorings are considered the same if one is a rotation of the other?

Comment: You should use Burnside's lemma.

Comment: Does each square have a different colour?

Comment: Hint: there are four rotations in the group $C_4$ acting on the squares. Factor them into cycles. For Burnside we need to count the colorings that are fixed by each permutation and average those counts. A coloring is fixed if it is constant on each cycle. How many admissible colorings does that produce for the four different permutations given that we have five available colors?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma#Example_application) is a similar example on wiki that will help you to find an answer.